# Connecting ancient times with modern times through medieval times

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, steganography, word-property

Fill in the blanks where applicable, based on the first few sentences:

1. Mr. Indiana can type in a minute nine difficult words.
2. Mr. Victor sows five rows of corns in twenty two days.
3. Ms. Xanthappe ran __ kilometres in ____ minutes.
4. That Llama is known to eat fifty pounds of fodder in ___ minutes.
5. Madam Camma lived for full ____ years in a third world country.
6. Lady Diana drove five hundred miles in a hurry fleeing from the ___ estate.
7. Did Madonna sing over ____ songs during the last thirteen years ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

3.Ms. Xanthappe ran __ kilometres in ____ minutes.

> Ms. Xanthappe ran 10 kilometres in 24 minutes.

4.That Llama is known to eat fifty pounds of fodder in ___ minutes.

> That Llama is known to eat fifty pounds of fodder in 12 minutes.

5.Madam Camma lived for full ____ years in a third world country.

> Madam Camma lived for full 100 years in a third world country.

6.Lady Diana drove five hundred miles in a hurry fleeing from the ___ estate.

> Lady Diana drove five hundred miles in a hurry fleeing from the 4th estate.

7.Did Madonna sing over ____ songs during the last thirteen years ?

> Did Madonna sing over 1000 songs during the last thirteen years ?

Rationale:

> The first letter of each name corresponds to 2 numbers:  the corresponding ROMAN NUMERAL (thanks Chowzen), and the index in the English alphabet (1=A, 2=B, ...).

Comment: That's correct. Well done.

Answer (score 8):

Well, to begin with,

> Each of the letters of the name are ROMAN NUMERALS, so
>  
>
>  Mr. Indiana can type in a minute nine difficult words. I = (one minute)
>  Mr. Victor sows five rows of corns in twenty two days. V = (five rows)
>  Ms. Xanthappe ran __ kilometres in ____ minutes. X = (10 Kilos)
>  That Llama is known to eat fifty pounds of fodder in __ minutes. L = (fifty pounds)
>  Madam Camma lived for full ____ years in a third world country. MC = (1100 years)
>  Lady Diana drove five hundred miles in a hurry fleeing from the ___ estate. LD = (450? miles)
>  Did Madonna sing over ____ songs during the last thirteen years ?  M = (1000 songs)

Still cogitating on the remainder...

Comment: Good attempt @Chowzen. Partially got it correct too.